# How to write a recursive method to return the sum of digits in an int?

Tags: java, recursion

So this is my code so far.

```
    public int getsum (int n){
        int num = 23456;
        int total = 0;
        while (num != 0) {
            total += num % 10;
            num /= 10;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that i cant/know how to change this into a recursive method
Im kind of new with recursion and i need some help on implementing this method to change it so its recursive.

Comment: to start in the world of recursive methods, you must define: 1. Basic Cases (num != 0 in this case), 2. The part of code you need to execute _many_ times, 3. your input parameters, 4. your output. Give it a try  and edit your question with your proposed solution so we can help you better.

Comment: looking at your profile it seems you've lots of issues related to recursion. Why not get a good programing book and start learning by trial-and-error?

Answer (score 18):

Short, recursive and does the job:

```
int getsum(int n) {
   return n == 0 ? 0 : n % 10 + getsum(n/10);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here it is,

```
//sumDigits function
int sumDigits(int n, int sum) {    
    // Basic Case to stop the recursion
if (n== 0)  {
        return sum;
    } else {
        sum = sum + n % 10;  //recursive variable to keep the digits sum
        n= n/10;
        return sumDigits(n, sum); //returning sum to print it.
    }
}
```

An example of the function in action:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int sum = sumDigits(121212, 0);
     System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: +1 for tail recursion. The shorter version:
    int sumDigits(int n, int sum) {
       return (n==0) ? 0 : n%10 + sumDigits(n/10, sum+n%10);
    }

Answer (score 3):

```
public int sumDigits(int n) {
    return (n - 1) % 9 + 1;
}
```

Comment: This method is not recursive!

Comment: Yeah but faster and shorter.

Comment: ...and incorrect. sumDigits(99) =>  98 % 9 + 1 = > 8 + 1 => 9...

Comment: Yes that is the correct answer. The original question is to calculate sum of digits until single digit number. So for 99:  9 + 9 = 18 => 1 + 8 = 9

Comment: I didn't see that this was asked initially, but a nice way to solve that :)

Comment: @VolkanSahin45 can you explain how you come up with that? it's so elegant!

Comment: @TFT I am not mathematician so I can't :D

Comment: Reason can be found here- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221698/why-is-the-sum-of-the-digits-in-a-multiple-of-9-also-a-multiple-of-9#:~:text=9%20is%20divisible%20by%209.&text=i.e.%2C%20n%20gives%20the%20same,digits%20is%20divisible%20by%209.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int sumOfDigit(int num){
    int sum=0;
    if (num == 0)
    return sum;
            sum = num%10 + sumOfDigit(num/10);
    return sum;
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input num : ");
    int num=input.nextInt();
    int s=sumOfDigit(num);
    System.out.println("Sum = "+s);
}
```

}

Comment: Please also add some explanation to your answer to help the asker understand the issue.

Comment: please explain detail with your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int getSum(int num)
{
    total = total + num % 10;
    num = num/10;
    if(num == 0)
    {
        return total;
    } else {
        return getSum(num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int getSum(int N)
{
    int totalN = 0;

    totalN += (N% 10);
    N/= 10;

    if(N == 0)
        return totalN;
    else 
        return getSum(N) + totalN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int digitSum (int n)
  { 
    int r = n%10;       //remainder, last digit of the number
    int num = n/10;     //the rest of the number without the last digit
    if(num == 0)
    {
      return n;
    } else {
      return digitSum (num) + r;
    }}
```

Comment: This is a code-only answer without commentary. Please provide an explanation o what you changed and why you changed it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for positive numbers.

```
public int sumDigits(int n) {
  int sum = 0;
  if(n == 0){
  return 0;
  }
  sum += n % 10; //add the sum
  n /= 10; //keep cutting
  return sum + sumDigits(n); //append sum to recursive call
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class Adder {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        System.out.println();
        int number = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The sum of the digits is " +adder(number));

    }
    public static int adder(int num){
        int length = String.valueOf(num).length();
        int first , last , sum;
        if (length==1){
            return num;
        }
        else
        {
            first = num /10;
            last = num % 10;
            sum = last + adder(first);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of solutions on here, but not one in which seems as simple as what follows. I've tested it countless times and it works no problem:

```
public int sumDigits(int n) {
  if (n == 0){
    return 0;
  }
  else{
    return n%10 + sumDigits(n/10);
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you didn't "see" [the top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9697072)... Yours does the exact same thing, just in a more verbose way.

Answer (score 0):

I used recursion method in java for finding the sum of digits of a number

```java
public class recursion_practice {
  static int sum(int n) {
      int sum = 0;
      if (n > 0) {
          int d = n % 10;
          sum += d;
          return sum + sum(n / 10);
      } else return 0;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int x = 123;
      System.out.println(sum(x)); // it will print 6 as 1+2+3=6
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this improve on the dozen other answers that have been left for this 10 year old question? If so, how?

Comment: It does matter when you are new to java and you are trying to do 10 years old question and also new to stackoverflow and trying to increase reputation to answer very frequently asked questions

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
int useRecursion(int x);
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"enter an integer: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<useRecursion(n)<<endl;
    return 0;
}

int useRecursion(int x){
    if(x/10 == 0)
        return x;
    else
        return useRecursion(x/10) + useRecursion(x%10);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's the shortest so far. The input thing is up too you, though.

```
 public static int getSum(int input)  {  //example: input=246
       int sum=0;   
       if (input%10==input)  { //246%10=6;  
              return input%10; //2%10=2
       }

       return input%10+getSum((input-input%10)/10); //(246-6)/10=24; 24%10=4
 }
```