# Sum of Digits / Digital Root using Recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to add the digits using the below code.
For example if my input is 678 my output should be 3.

eg.

> digital_root(942)
> => 9 + 4 + 2
> => 15 ...
> => 1 + 5
> => 6

```
package codewars;
        
public class test 
{
    static int sum(int s)
    {
        int n=s;
        int add=0;
        while(n % 10 > 0)       
        {
            add = n % 10 + add;
            n = n / 10;
            //System.out.println("num is "  +n );
        }
                 
        if(add / 10 > 0)
        {
            System.out.println(add);
            sum(add);
            System.out.println("if block");
        }
                
        return add;
    }
        
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int result = test.sum(678);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
      
}
```

I want to call the `sum` function recursively till the sum consists of single digits only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a recursive method to return the sum of digits in an int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696853/how-to-write-a-recursive-method-to-return-the-sum-of-digits-in-an-int)

Comment: Your algorithm is recursively calling sum. But you are forgetting to use the result of the recursive call. When you need to call the sum method in the if statement then you need to return that result as final result. So just add the return keyword in front of sum(add). Currently your recursive call is executed but you don't do anything with the result which is the same as just removing the if statement and its body. Added correct code to my answer below.

Comment: @Juru Thanks .The code works now

Comment: Just some last advice. Recursiveness can be used in many ways, this is just one where the final recursion determines the overall result. Sometimes results need to be concatenated or you could pass an argument that accumulates the results and so on. But recursion also often causes memory issues so beware of that. All recursions can be written as a loop by the way.

Comment: @Juru But your solution is using recursion too

Comment: Yes, not saying that it is pure evil. Its handy and sometimes the most readable solution. The point is that you don't use it blindly because it is easy for a particular problem. But for most common problems, like this one, it is ok as I don't expect the depth of recursion to be very high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something more close to your own algorithm. Does not use mod anywhere though, instead it transforms the number into a string and adds all the numeric values of the characters together each pass. Easier to understand but maybe not as performant(? to be tested).

```
public class Test{
            static int sum(final int s)
            {
                final String numbers = String.valueOf(s);
                final int amountOfDigits = numbers.length();
                int sum = Character.getNumericValue(numbers.charAt(0));
                for(int i = 1; i < amountOfDigits; i++) {
                    sum += Character.getNumericValue(numbers.charAt(i));
                }
                
                if(sum > 9) {
                    return sum(sum);    
                } else {
                    return sum;
                }
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
                int result = Test.sum(678);
                System.out.println(result);
            }
}
```

To fix your own code just add return to the recursive call. Otherwise you always return the sum of all the digits of the initial number, which you only want to do when there is only one digit left.

```
static int sum(int s)
            {
                int n=s;
                int add=0;
                while(n%10 > 0)        
                {
                    add = (n%10) +add;
                    n = n/10;
                    System.out.println("num is "  +n );
                }

                if(add/10 > 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(add);
                    return sum(add);
                }
                return add;
            }
```

Comment: Just for the record. The method using mod instead of characters is 25% faster :-).

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following code -

```
public class DigitalRoot{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Digital Root 9: "+findDigitalRoot(9));
        System.out.println("Digital Root 942: "+findDigitalRoot(942));
        System.out.println("Digital Root 1942: "+findDigitalRoot(1942));
        System.out.println("Digital Root 1876: "+findDigitalRoot(1876));
    }

    public static int findDigitalRoot(int n) {

        if(n>10){

            int sum = n%10 + findDigitalRoot(n/10);
            if(sum>10){
                return findDigitalRoot(sum);
            }else{
                return sum;
            }
        }else{
            return n;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: OK.Can you let me know what is the issue in my code?
Why i am not able to call sum function recursively

Answer (score 1):

This covers the case where the inner result is greater than 10:

```
static int sum(int s) {

    if (s >= 10) {
        int t = s % 10 + sum(s / 10);
        if (t >= 10) {
            return sum(t);
        } else {
            return t;
        }

    } else {
        return s;
    }
}
```

The following compact function produces the same output:

```
static int sum(int s) {

    if (s < 10) {
        return s;
    }

    return sum(s % 10 + sum(s / 10));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out about an easier solution, using a mathematical relation about sum of digits

```
static int sum(int n) {
     return (n - 1) % 9 + 1;
}
```

**PS: just try it in your console.**

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with the following way:

```
public class DRoot {
  public static int digital_root(int n) {
  int sum=0;
  String s=String.valueOf(n);
  for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
    int a=Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));    
    sum+=a;
  }

  if(sum > 9) {
      return digital_root(sum);    
  } else {
      return sum;
    }
  }

}
```